# What is the earliest use of "You just/still don't get it do you?"

Tags: dialogue, first-appearance

There is a [funny montage](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4KoKWf6pLs8) of movie and TV clips on YouTube in which variations of the phrase "you don't get it, do you" are used.  Sometime after I watched that video I saw a 1959 episode of *Bat Masterson* entitled "Wanted: Dead."  In it actor John Dehner said to Gene Barry, "You just don't get it, do you Masterson?  They all killed that boy."  I laughed out loud and then wondered just how long this phrase has been in use.

What is the earliest use of the phrase "You [still/just] don't get it, do you?" in movies and television?

Comment: To be honest, I think it's not so much just a movie/tv thing but rather a common thing to say in relevant situations..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the script search site [Subzin](http://www.subzin.com/), I found no instances of the phrase in use prior to 1959.  A naive search produced several candidates; I've listed them below.  All of these turned out to be either foreign films with English subtitles added later, or English language films incorrectly titled or incorrectly dated or both.

- *Noored Kotkad*: 1927 Estonian film.
- *The Devil's Parade*: 1930 musical, purported script actually was *The Devil Wears Prada*.
- *Love Is On The Air*: 1937 film, purported script referred to "the internet."
- *When The Lights Go On Again*: 1944 film, purported script contains post-1959 references.
- *Nachts, wenn der Teufel kam*: 1957 German film.

So barring new developments, the answer is still 1959, *Bat Masterson*.